# The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm developing an Android app using C# and it initially was building perfectly. I closed down Visual Studio 2015 and re-opened it, tried to build and I am now presented with the following error

> The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist.   PreOrderApp

I have not added or deleted any files.

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you try a Xamarin.Forms Portable project and deploy. Please try and write events. When i open Xamarin.Forms Shared i take that errors sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I had wrong format of Android Version number in Android Manifest. You have to use integer values for Android Version number.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have some file with "-" like "icon-test.png" and change to "_" like "icon_test.png".

You can also check if you have some blank space in name files.

Comment: In my case, my files is blank space

Comment: Thanks Danilo, I changed the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can find a bug report on this issue:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55232

The main cause of this issue is that the `aapt` errors are not being propagated to the `Error List`. Thus it is difficult to debug and requires a bit more attention.

You can get your `Diagnostic Build Output` via the following:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output

Once you have that, you should be able to view `APT` errors inside the log which will tell you why the `aapt` task has failed. You need to correct these to then generated a new `Resource.designer.cs` file. Otherwise it will continue to throw the `error MSB3375: The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist.` error.

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed this issue. Check to see if there are any unused entries in resources.designer.cs if there are any manually remove those entries. 
This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by installing the latest version of the Android SDK Build Tool:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem before , i discovered that the main reason is that i added anew Image resource and contains "-" , which cause error , try to take care of your resources as xamarin maps it to variables in memory and some times its name cause errors