# obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources doesn't exist

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm making a flag quiz app using xamarin and I am getting the following error in my project.
"obj\Debug\res\drawable\uzbekistan.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited (TaskId:218)".
I have figured out its in my drawable but i cannot locate it..Please help me through

Comment: Does "drawable\uzbekistan.png" exist in your Xamarin.Android project?

Comment: yes sir, it does and so does all other flags.

Comment: Can you check replacing it with a copy of the default icon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged\_resources" does not exist Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742705/the-file-obj-debug-android-bin-packaged-resources-does-not-exist-xamarin-andro)